# zip not extracting created using DotnetZip (Ionic.zip)(1.10.1)

Tags: asp.net, webforms, dotnetzip, .net-framework-version

I am using DotNetZip.dll(1.10.1) for creating zip files(media files), Files get zipped but when I try to extract it using WinRaR or with windows extract folder option, I am getting "*the archive is unknown format or damaged*"

```
List<string> fileNames = new List<string>();
    using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
                {
                    //zip.CompressionLevel = Ionic.Zlib.CompressionLevel.BestCompression;
                    zip.ParallelDeflateThreshold = -1;
                    zip.Encryption = EncryptionAlgorithm.None;
                    zip.AddFiles(fileNames.AsEnumerable(),"");

                    zip.Save(zipSavePath);
                }
```

CRC32 of zipped file is 00000000.

I am using .net framework 4.0 and web forms.

Can you please let me what wrong am I doing

Thanks

Comment: everything is working not an issue in code.

Comment: Can you extract the zip file that you have created with winRAR or from windows

Comment: yes i cant find any issue while extract i have extract both the way using windows and winrar.

Comment: I figured out the issue, the problem was not with the zip file but when I was sending that zip as response to the client, i was not closing the response. so Response.Close() did the trick